# How to use pyrebase order_by_key correctly?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have a function which I'm trying to make return a list of ordered keys (which are in date format). I have

```
        data = database.child('users').child(num).child('details').get().val()
```

and then

```
        return render(request, "page2.html", {'list':(list(data.keys()))})
```

This works correctly but returns them in random order in terms of key values.

I've tried variations of something like:

```
        data = database.child('users').child(num).child('details').order_by_key().get().val()
```

or

```
        data = database.child('users').child(num).child('details').order_by_key().get()
```

but I'm obviously missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `.val()` the data gets converted to a dictionary (or the equivalent Python structure) and any information about the order is lost.

To maintain the order, you must process the results in order by using [Pyrebase's `each` function](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#each).